# Homework: determining if a space is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question is from an assignment I'm working on:

> Which of the following are subspaces of ${\bf F}~[-1,1]=\{~f~|~f:[-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$?
>
> $X=\{~f\in{\bf F}[-1,1]~|~f(-1)=f(1)\}$
>
> $Y=\{~f\in{\bf F}[-1,1]~|~f(0)=-1\}$
>
> $Z=\{~f\in{\bf F}[-1,1]~|~f(x)=f(y)~\forall~x,y\in[-1,1]\}$
>
> $W=\{~f\in{\bf F}[-1,1]~|~f(-1)\le 0\}$

So far, I've found that:

- X cannot be a subspace of ${\bf F}$ as it is outside of the domain of ${\bf F}$ when $x>-1$
- Y cannot be a subspace of ${\bf F}$ either, as $f(x<0)$ is outside the domain of ${\bf F}$ as well
- I'm entirely unsure whether Z is a subspace of ${\bf F}$, and I'm not even sure how to evaluate Z.
- I think that W is not a subspace of ${\bf F}$, as it is outside the domain of ${\bf F}$ for $x>0$, although I'm hesitant to put this down as a justification.

This being said, I'm fairly new to linear algebra, and those answers could be wrong.

My biggest issue is with W, since I have no idea where to start.

Any suggestions on how W can be evaluated, and feedback on the answers I've already found?

Comment: You probably may need more explanation of what $\mathbf F[-1,1]$ is as a set. The functions are defined as having domain [-1, 1], so for _any_ member $f$ of $\mathbf F[-1,1]$, all the values of $x$ with $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ are in it's domain, by definition. There is also $\mathcal C[-1, 1]$, the set of all continuous functions on $[-1, 1]$, which is a subspace of $\mathbf F[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F=\left\{f\mid f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R\right\}$

---

For a set $S$ to be a subspace of $F$, you need:

- $S\subseteq F$
- $\forall f,g \in S, f + g \in S$
- $\forall f \in S,\forall \lambda \in \Bbb R, \lambda f \in S$

---

Since all your sets are written as $\left\{f\in F \mid \dots\right\}$, it is obvious that they are all subsets of $F$ so we only need to check the two other requirements.

---

$X=\left\{f\in F \mid f(-1)=f(1)\right\}$

- Let $f,g \in X$.
  $(f+g)(-1)=f(-1)+g(-1)=f(1)+g(1)=(f+g)(1)$ so $f+g\in X$
- Let $f\in X$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. $(\lambda f)(-1)=\lambda(f(-1))=\lambda(f(1))=(\lambda f)(1)$ so $\lambda f \in X$

So $X$ is a subspace of $F$.

---

$Y=\left\{f\in F \mid f(0)=-1\right\}$

- Let $f,g \in X$.
  $(f+g)(0)=f(0)+g(0)=(-1) +(-1)=-2\not = 0$ so $f+g\not\in X$

That's how you would see that it doesn't work but you don't need a result that strong. You only need one counterexample.

For example take $f=g=x\mapsto -1$. It is easy to see that $f=g\in Y$ but $f+g\not\in Y$ so $Y$ is not a subspace.

---

$Z=\left\{f\in F \mid \forall x, y \in [-1,1],f(x)=f(y)\right\}$

- Let $f,g \in Z$.
  $\forall x,y \in [-1,1],(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=f(y)+g(y)=(f+g)(y)$ so $f+g\in Z$
- Let $f\in Z$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. $\forall x,y \in [-1,1], (\lambda f)(x)=\lambda(f(x))=\lambda(f(y))=(\lambda f)(y)$ so $\lambda f \in Z$

So $Z$ is a subspace of $F$.

---

Do you see why $X$ is a subspace? $x>-1$ isn't out of the domain (as long as $x\le 1$): the domain still is $[-1,1]$. The $f(-1)=f(1)$ is just an additionnal condition.

Anyway, try to find the answer for the two last onces like I did: Take elements and show combinaisons are inside or, if you get blocked at some point, try to find a counterexample.

---

As Geoff Pointer pointed out in the comments, you also need $0\in S$ for $S$ to be a subspace. It is trivial both all sets except $Y$ where it fails. So just saying $0\not\in Y$ would be enough to prove it's not a subspace.

Comment: Alright, I've tried finding an answer for the remaining sets, and I've tested $W$ for both scalar multiplication and vector addition, and have found it to be $W\in {\bf F}$. I'm still stuck at Z; still have no idea where to start.

Comment: You can't write $W\in F$. You can write $W\subseteq F$ but that only means it's a subset. To say it's a subspace, you have to use English. And are you sure you tested scalar multiplication properly? What happens when you have a negative scalar?

Comment: And $Z$ is the set of constant functions. Can you see why? The proof should look like the one I did for $X$ except that instead of $-1$ and $1$, you have $x$ nd $y$.

Comment: I can see why $Z$ is a set of constant functions, but wouldn't that fact alone mean that they exist only between $[-1,1]$? And good catch on $W$.

Comment: The function is defined only on $[-1,1]$... I think you are confused about what a function is. You might want to read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384623/function-notation/384774#384774

Comment: Or maybe you didn't know how to quantify $x$ and $y$. I added a solution for $Z$. Does that help?

Comment: Actually, I understand a bit better now. I was confused as to how  one is to interpret a function as a vector.

Comment: And thanks for the solution to Z. What I was working on resembled this.

Comment: @xavierm02 This is not the way I understand how you answer the question whether or not a subset of a given vector space is a subspace. It's given that it's a subset of the vector space. The usual theorem for a subspace is that it's a non empty closed subset of the vector space. You have to show it's non empty first and then show it's closed under the vector space operations. The usual way to show it's non empty is to show it contains the zero vector which is usually a trivial exercise.

Comment: @xavierm02 You have a typo in your last section where you say $x > 1$ isn't out of the domain.

Comment: @Geoff Pointer Fixed.